# Adding an offset to stat_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working with a dataset where I have to transform some data for a curve fit.  I'm plotting it using `ggplot2`, and can use `stat_smooth` on the transformed data to get the fit, but then want to overlay the result on the correct datapoints.

As a toy example, let's say I had

```
qplot(1:10, 1:10)+stat_smooth(formula=y+1~x, method="lm")
```

But I want to shift the stat_smooth line down by one (other than by taking the +1 out of the formula).  Is this possible?

Comment: You can fit any number of formulas and model structures within `stat_smooth()`. It isn't entirely clear to me what you are after, but the answer will probably be outlined here: http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/stat_smooth.html

Comment: You're probably better off fitting the model and doing the transformation outside of ggplot2.

Comment: This makes almost no sense to me.  You are making a transformation of y by adding 1 to it, and then want to subtract 1 from y without taking +1 out of the formula?  Are you sure this is what you want to do?  Did you actually mean y~x+1?  I suspect your real problem is something else.  If you give us more information, we might be able to help.

Comment: @Andrie : it's a toy example. I just find it funny that by constructing the toy example, he gives the solution for his own (difficult to understand) problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes things can be very obvious :

```
qplot(1:10, 1:10)+stat_smooth(formula=(y+1)-1~x, method="lm")
```

If you can raise it 1 by adding 1 to y, you can lower it 1 by substracting 1 from y. ;-)

Comment: That's perfect!  And thanks for taking the toy example as just that, a toy example!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `position_nudge()` was available when this was asked 10.5 years ago but it's provided a simpler way of doing this for some time (as of ggplot 3.3.5, late 2021).

```
qplot(1:10, 1:10 + rnorm(10, sd = 0.3)) + stat_smooth(formula = y~x, method = "lm", position = position_nudge(y = 1))
```

It seems worth cautioning there's a good chance of displaying confusing or misleading confidence intervals when manipulating `stat_smooth()`'s formula. I've added a bit of variation to `qplot()`'s input in the line above [to illustrate this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5L6A.png).