# Create lines parallel to my `geom_smooth(method = lm)` line

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = lm)
```

I would like two purple lines to run parallel to my `geom_smooth(method = lm)` line. Each line should be 10 units away from the `geom_smooth(method = lm)` line. One line would be above, and the other line below the `geom_smooth(method = lm)` line.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5483834/1320535) suggests, there doesn't seem to be a natural way to shift a line. What we may do then is to use multiple `geom_smooth` with different offsets:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  lapply(c(-10, 0, 10), function(o)
    geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y + o ~ x))
```

[image]